# Chat application through php

Tags: php, chat

I want to build a chat application using PHP. Does anybody have any idea about it? If so please reply.
The chat application must be user friendly, multiple chatting scenario must be there.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds pretty straight forward.

Ajax-polling front-end -> chat_handler.php -> backend database

Done.

Comment: exactly. i've done a bunch of them just for my own pleasure :)

Comment: I did a school project that did exactly that. For an art class even.

Comment: To be fair, it was a computer art class, and it had a Director movie where parts would change based on keywords said in the chat.

Comment: Sounds like some video-mashup nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a "Shoutout" type public chat system, it's pretty easy to achieve via PHP/MySQL/jQuery.

You just have to take input from a form. jQuery will submit values to a database via a backend php file.

To refresh the submitted messages after regular intervals you can use setInterval function availabe in jQuery.

Maybe this will help:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Answer (score -3):

just buy one if you don't want to code. Comet Chat is a good one, like Faceb00k. Just google